# Absolute image animate behing another div - Angular 5 animation

Tags: css, angular, animation, angular5, angular-animations

I have an image I want to animate, it should slide bottom up to its position. I'm using Angular 5 animations and so far my animation works, but not exacly as I want it. Please check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LT2DeOpfEDAYDRGCVpBq?p=preview) as it is an example of what I have.

Ok, I have two `div`'s with `height: 50%`. The top `div` has an image (represented as a red square in the plunker) set with `position: absolute`.
I'm animating this image (red square) to appear from bottom to up, but the problem is:

**I want the image to come from the bottom, but behing the bottom div** and it is coming in front of it.

I tried `z-index`, didn't work, figure out why, couldn't think of another way that didn't sound like a cheap and ugly workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add **position: relative;** along with z-index to #bottom div.

```
#bottom {
  background: #a3c6ff;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```